# A way to do this curve lines effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

i really try many ways to do this lines (use the blend tool too by the way) and no have luck. Is any way to do this lines (the blue lines)?

[image: See the blue lines]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieve that effect with the blend tool. Maybe you weren't doing it like this:

First draw the top line, then draw the bottom line.

Adjust the blend options: Object>Blend>Blend Options. Select Specified Steps and for number of steps it looks like you need 5.

Select both with black arrow and click Object >Blend>Make.

This should give you all the paths but they are not yet fillable.

Select your blend, click Object>Expand, then Object>Ungroup.

Draw a rectangle as wide as you need the image to be, full screen size. Make the rectangle have stroke of 1 and no fill.

Make sure your group of lines (it's no longer a blend) extends past the rectangle own both sides.

Select rectangle and lines and open Pathfinder panel and hit Divide.

Select rectangle and lines and Ungroup. Delete top and bottom of rectangle and any lines that extend past the sides.

You should now have the finished shape which can be filled with the magic paintbucket tool.

Collect your blue tints. I would make 4 rectangles filled with the blue colors to get them right.

Select first blue color, open magic paintbucket and fill first shape between top 2 lines. Select second blue and fill second shape with paintbucket. Continue with the rest of the shapes.

Select all and turn off the stroke and you are done.